# Stateless authentication with ServiceStack using OAuth

Tags: servicestack

I have an app (http://github.com/joshilewis/lending) that is using ServiceStack (version 3.9.71 for licence reasons). Currently its using cookie/session-based auth, with the built-in OAuth auth providers. I would like to move to stateless, token-based authentication, where the client sends a token with every request, which is validated with the OAuth auth service.

Does ServiceStack 3.9.71) support this?

Comment: Never used it, but here's a [JWT Stateless Auth example](https://github.com/rvhelden/StatelessAuthentication).

Comment: Thanks @mythz, I'll have a look